# How to check if a word is a palindrome without using "string.reverse" method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use Ruby to check if a word is a palindrome, but I'm not allowed to use built-in functions like `str.reverse`. How should I tackle this problem?

Below is the code with the `.reverse` method, it works, but I'm not sure how to check if a word is a palindrome without the `.reverse`.

```rb
def palindrome(word)
  i = 0
  if word.reverse == word
    puts "#{word} is a palindrome!"
  else
    puts "#{word} is not a palindrome"
  end
end

puts palindrome("peep")
```

It should print something like "racecar is a palindrome!".

Comment: You could create your own reverse function, that way you could use your current comparison and you wouldn't use the built-in function.

Comment: Split the string into an array of characters, iterate over the array and check if the current character is the same as the one in a corresponding position on the opposite end.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "not allowed to use built-in functions"? For example, [Cary Swoveland's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966826/2988) uses no less than *eight* "built-in functions" (`String#size`, `Integer#/`, `Integer#times`, `Enumerable#all?`, `String#[]`, `String#==`, `Integer#-@`, and `Integer#-`). [Aetherus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966810/2988) uses eight for the first solution and six for the second. [Emu's partial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966713/2988) uses three just to implement reversing the string, and you will need at least one more.

Comment: Here is a question on [codereview.se] that may be of interest to you: [Find a palindrome using Ruby](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/121004/1581).

Answer (score 4):

```
def pal(str) 
  (str.size/2).times.all? { |i| str[i] == str[-i-1] }
end
```

```
pal "11211"  #=> true
pal "1"      #=> true
pal ""       #=> true
pal "12111"  #=> false
```

Comment: Nice solution using `all?`

Answer (score 1):

The most classical solution: compare the first character with the last character, if they are the same, compare the second character with the second last character..., until you find a pair of different characters or you have exausted the whole string (except the charater in the middle if the string has a odd length).

```
def palindrome?(string)
  (string.length / 2).times.reduce(true) do |palindrome, i|
    palindrome && string[i] == string[-i - 1]
  end
end
```

And here's a tail-recursive solution just for fun (Neither MRI nor JRuby optimizes tail recursion):

```
def palindrome?(string, i = 0, j = string.length - 1)
  return true if i >= j
  string[i] == string[j] && palindrome?(string, i + 1, j - 1)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way to reverse the string without `.reverse` is

`"11211".chars.reduce { |x, y| y + x }  # => "11211"`

so, you can also check this way too.